# how to create a sliding open door effect

Tags: jquery-animate, sliding-doors

i'm looking to create a sliding open door effect with jquery that has the following functionality:

- arrive on the page and the doors are closed
- click a link and the doors slide outwards a fixed amount on the x-axis
- click the same link again and the doors close

i started out with the concept here, which works great:

http://buildinternet.com/2009/07/animate-curtains-opening-with-jquery/

but realised that i wanted the doors to slide across, rather than shrink in size, using the type of functionality seen here:

http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

so i think what i am looking for is some type of 'animate' functionality:

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

this is the logic of the functionality i am trying to achieve:

**static state:**
background: an image that is revealed when the doors slide open.
door-left-inner: 122px wide x 244px high, centered and offset left -61px with z-index 3.
door-left-outer: 122px wide x 244px high, centered and offset left -151px with z-index 2.
door-right-inner: 122px wide x 244px high, centered and offset right 61px with z-index 3.
door-right-outer: 122px wide x 244px high, centered and offset right 151px with z-index 2.

**onclick** (all these functions take place at the same time):
door-left-inner x-position slide on click:  -164px on x-axis.
door-left-outer x-position slide on click:  -74px on x-axis.
door-right-inner x-position slide on click:  164px on x-axis.
door-right-outer x-position slide on click:  74px on x-axis.

here is a diagram of what i am trying to achieve:

[image]

**attempted code** (not currently working)

`$("#open_close_doors").click(function(){ $("#leftdoor_inner").animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "slow");});​`

and here is my jsfiddle attempt at getting one of the doors to slide - i figure once i know how to get one of the doors sliding i'll be able to apply the same logic to the others. also i'm a relative newb to jquery.

http://jsfiddle.net/9zsdN/

thank you.

Comment: Hey, it was an elementary error. No worries, it's working fine now. Check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the corrected jsFiddle for the same: http://jsfiddle.net/9zsdN/1/

```
$("#open_close_doors").click(function(){ $("#leftdoor_inner").animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "slow");});​
```

It should be:

```
$(".open_close_doors").click(function(){
  $("#leftdoor_inner").animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "slow");
});​
```

The difference lies in the way you access an element. As you can see, when you access an element by class, you use " `.classsname`" instead of "<strike>`#classname`</strike>" as you have done.

"`#name`" is used for accessing elements by their id.

Comment: ah! thank you, fantastic! ah, i can't believe i didn't see that, perfect, thank you!

Comment: for those interested, there is a revamped jsfiddle here with working open close functionality.  http://jsfiddle.net/9zsdN/3/.  contributed by user here http://stackoverflow.com/a/13064976/1063287